# In Flutter is there a way to check if the visible page has been presented modally

Tags: flutter

This is a common problem with iOS and is easily solved as all `UIViewControllers` have the property to check how they have been presented; whether modally or by being pushed onto a stack.

In `Flutter` we don't have view controllers, so we push new routes and one of the options is to use a `fullScreenDialog`. Your app bar will then have a close button and automatically `pop` when tapped.

But, if you want to dynamically adjust your `Scaffold` widgets based on whether they are presented in this way or not, there doesn't seem to be a way to detect that you are in a `fullScreenDialog` state (or modal). I have some pages that are part of the root tab navigation and therefore show a tab bar to switch between sections. I would like to reuse some of these pages but present them modally. In this case I want to remove the tab bar.

Is there any way to detect if a `Navigator` or `Scaffold` has been presented modally? Or do I just have to pass in a `isModal` bool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to determine weather the current route is fullscreen or just a modal you can use the following simple line:

```dart
final isModal = ModalRoute.of(context) is PopupRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of perhaps a different solution based on your need and usecase.
It's respectable the you'd rather not repeat code just to get rid of an appBar when it's not needed.

Here's my suggestion, that would work with and take advantage of the framework rather than fight it.

1. Create your `MultiPurposeSuperUsefulWidget`, without a scaffold or appBar.
2. This widget can be shown easily without problems even needed with tabBar navigation.
3. The obstacle is wanting to use this in modal mode, you have the option to create this modal widget/screen template, that takes a `final Widget widget` constructor.
4. Customize this modal template in the way you like, and let's call it `ModalTemplateScreen`.
5. Finally, when you want your `MultiPurposeSuperUsefulWidget` to be displayed in modal style, navigate to `ModalTemplateScreen(widget: MultiPurposeSuperUsefulWidget)` and pass your reusable widget as an argument.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it’s not just the app bar or the bottom navigation that needs to change based on modality, elements of the body may need to push other routes and know that they are hosted by the modal template.

Comment: I believe they you know before hand while writing your code what screens and widgets will be displayed in either pattern. For modality, you can put your desired behaviors in this single template.

Answer (score 0):

To set properties of your app bar based on modality you need to access the current `Route` and then check if the route was presented as a `fullscreenDialog`

```
isModal = (ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute).fullscreenDialog;
```